Woocommerce Custom code no longer working
I have a custom post type called Composers. I have code to extract the post content and display it on a Product Description Page template in a WordPress 2024 (child) theme. This code has been working fine up to a very recent WooCommerce update. The code is
// Function to get the composer post content by title
function get_composer_content_by_title( $title ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'composers',
        'name' => sanitize_title( $title ),
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $composer_posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !empty( $composer_posts ) ) {
        return $composer_posts[0]->post_content;
    }

    return ''; // Return empty string if no post found
}

// Shortcode to display the composer content
function display_composer_content_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'button_text' => 'Show Composer Info',
    ), $atts );

    global $post;
    $composer_title = get_field( 'composer', $post->ID );
    $composer_content = get_composer_content_by_title( $composer_title );

    // Button to show/hide the composer content
    $output = '<button class="show_composer" onclick="toggleComposerContent()">' . esc_html( $atts['button_text'] ) . '</button>';
    $output .= '<div id="composerContent" style="display:none;">' . $composer_content . '</div>';

    // Add some JavaScript to handle the toggle
    $output .= '<script>
        function toggleComposerContent() {
            var content = document.getElementById("composerContent");
            if (content.style.display === "none") {
                content.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'composer_info', 'display_composer_content_shortcode' );

Essentially, press the button show the composer details for this publication and again to hide it.
Eventually I intend to hide the button if there is no post and change the Button text, but for now I need to get this working. I can't see what might have changed that stops the code from getting the post content.
The last time I test this code was Friday. It worked, but not today, and on two different websites on different host platforms.

Just found out that what broke this code was a security update from WooCommerce yesterday. This necessitated a complete rewrite and so normal service has been resumed.
